# Remove directory name from URL using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have bunch of folders and files in folder "front". I want to remove "front" from url. I write htacess but it gives 404 error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^front/(.*)$ /test/$1 [L,NC,R]
```

I want to rewrite url like this :

```
http://localhost/test/front/abc/abc.php
```

to

```
http://localhost/test/abc/abc
```

Comment: Is htaccess inside the test folder?

Comment: yes, this htacess is inside the test folder

Answer (score 0):

You have it back to front

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /test/front/$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root, preferably above any rules you may already have there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /front/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: this will remove /test/ too

Comment: is that subfolder ??